# Error en psycopg2 SOLO en ejecutable de py2exe

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Estoy experimentando un error al que no le encuentro ni lógica ni solución...

Tengo un programa con el siguiente código

```
...
query = f"INSERT INTO nichos VALUES {parameters}"
try:
    run_query(query)
    print()
    print("Nicho agregado exitosamente.")
    print()
    if ret == 1:
        return cod_nicho
except sql.errors.UniqueViolation:
    print()
    print("         ERROR. El nicho ya se encuentra cargado en el sistema. No se realizaron cambios en el registro.")
    if ret == 0:
        return
    elif ret == 1:
        return cod_nicho
except:
    log_error()
    print("")
    input("         ERROR. Comuníquese con el administrador...  Presione enter para continuar...")
    if ret == 0:
        return
    elif ret == 1:
        return cod_nicho
...
```

Resulta que cuando lo ejecuto desde la consola de Windows ($ py script.py) funciona perfectamente, cuando ingreso un nicho con un id existente ejecuta el primer `except`...

Sin embargo, cuando hago lo mismo desde el .exe creado con `py2exe` me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "funciones_mantenimiento.pyc", line 1459, in alta_nicho
  File "funciones_mantenimiento.pyc", line 160, in run_query
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: llave duplicada viola restricción de unicidad «sqlite_autoindex_nichos_1»
DETAIL:  Ya existe la llave (codigo)=(0202010036).


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ventas.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "funciones_ventas.pyc", line 383, in menu
  File "funciones_ventas.pyc", line 1628, in menu_editar_op
  File "funciones_ventas.pyc", line 1823, in cambiar_nicho
  File "funciones_mantenimiento.pyc", line 1465, in alta_nicho
AttributeError: module 'psycopg2' has no attribute 'errors'
```

A alguien se le ocurre una explicación y una forma de solucionarlo?

Desde ya muchas Gracias...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bien, me dijeron que pruebe con `import psycopg2.errors` y funcionó a la perfección.

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta.